# XML To JSON and Vice Versa

Tags: google-apps-script

Team,
    This has been a problem in apps-script development for me.   I have been trying to solve it for quite some time.

The XML appscript service I have been using (now deprecated) has been doing excellent, I mean really awesome JOB of parsing the any html file or XML file with the linient flag turned of.  I am in love with it.

Also, this service gives you a JSON view of XML file.  that is really cool. because I can simply browse to any data item in the debugger, and then type that in code. No need to call many sensless methods when you know exactly what your code is looking for.
These AWESOME features in deprecated XML service make the job a lot easier than the so called XMLService which it replaces. 
One issue, I did find with XML service is it is slow.  I wrote a parser that does it within 10 seconds that XML Service takes 3 minutes. So, sure it is bad. 
But, XMLService does not have those neat features.

IS there any public code or libraries by anyone that does a beautiful job of:
a. Converting XML to JSON view.
b. Parse HTML in linient form.
c. Do it fast

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I didn't receive any update on the matter. So, I have written it myself. I simply convert XML to JSON.

Xml2Json will represent an XML string as a JSON object.

If you set flags="attributes", then the element attributes are packaged in XmlAttributes child of the JSONobject.

In XML, there is no way to say, you are about to encounter an array of elements or a single element.  So, the parser by default creates a JSON object out of an element unless it counters another xml element with same name, then it converts the Object into an Array.

Here is the Xml2Json Project Key: 18Aji4ggm4A2cXQ1n_sSc6gDQA3Wc4aC5WvQYybAflkdUushu9f2Ogv5o

Comment: Could you please share sample source code? That will really help us.

Answer (score 0):

**XML**

```
const xml = `
    <user>
      <first_name>Foo</first_name>
      <last_name>Bar</last_name>
      <birth_date>Apr 20, 1987</birth_date>
      <user_id>2020592</user_id>
      <phone>
        <type>mobile</type>
        <number>1234567890</number>
      </phone>
      <phone>
        <type>work</type>
        <number>0987654321</number>
      </phone>
      <address>
        <street>1234 Highway Blvd</street>
        <city>Houston</city>
        <state>TX</state>
        <zip>77022</zip>
      </address>
    </user>`
```

**JSON Output**

```
{
    "first_name": "Foo",
    "last_name": "Bar",
    "birth_date": "Apr 20, 1987",
    "user_id": 2020592,
    "phone": [
        {
            "type": "mobile",
            "number": 1234567890
        },
        {
            "number": "0987654321",
            "type": "work"
        }
    ],
    "address": {
        "city": "Houston",
        "zip": 77022,
        "state": "TX",
        "street": "1234Highway Blvd"
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
  const root = XmlService.parse(xml).getRootElement();
  const json = elementToJSON(root)
```

**Function**

```
function elementToJSON(element) {
  var result = {};
  // Attributes.
  element.getAttributes().forEach(function (attribute) {
    result[attribute.getName()] = attribute.getValue();
  });
  // Child elements.
  element.getChildren().forEach(function (child) {
    var key = child.getName();
    var value = elementToJSON(child);
    if (result[key]) {
      if (!(result[key] instanceof Array)) {
        result[key] = [result[key]];
      }
      result[key].push(value);
    } else {
      result[key] = value;
    }
  });
  // Text content.
  if(!element.getChildren().length) result = element.getText();

  return result;
}
```